# changing the displayed "From" field in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

when an email-address is stored in thunderbird's address book, it uses the name stored there to display as the sender in the thread-pane, and ignores any value in the email.

e.g. my address book has "John Doe ", which means that all emails with the header "From: Netochka Nezvanova (via J.Doe) " are displayed as being sent from "John Doe".

i assume that this is to deface some kind of email forgery (e.g. "Bank of America " will not appear to be an official email), but i fail to see how it should work in practice.

what's more, I *do want* to see the original values in the "From"-field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out that in the thunderbird address book, you can disable the option

> [x] *Always prefer display name over message header.*

which uses (as the name suggests) the display name in the message header.